# Android Custom WebView

Tags: java, android, email

I have made a custom webview which is used to open a very heavy site in terms of database. The webview uses custom code for uploading files using an upload handler class. I need suggestions on how I can optimize my code for better performance.

Features necessary (current custom webview written below does it all):

1. The basic functionality is just to load a responsive WordPress website.
2. Webview should support image uploading features.
3. mailto: links should open in the default email client.

I am adding the complete main activity page for your reference.

```
package com.Example.application;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;




import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

      final Context context = this;
    private WebView webView;
     private ImageButton btnrefresh;    
     private TextView txtrefresh;
     private Menu optionsMenu;
     private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
        private View mCustomView;




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //define button 
        btnrefresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        btnrefresh.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnrefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //define textView
        txtrefresh = (TextView)findViewById((R.id.textView1));
        txtrefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        if(isConnected())
        {

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
               webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

                webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
                webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
                webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        //  webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
          webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
          {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


              if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                  sendEmail(url.substring(7));
                  return true;
              }

              return false;
          }

        });


            initWebView(webView);                         
            webView.loadUrl("http://Example.com/");             

            }


        else
        {
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code formatting needs a lot of work, I couldn't even read through the code because I kept getting lost.

- Be consistent with your bracing style

  - pick one and stick to it
- Get rid of unnecessary whitespace

  - too many extra lines
- Don't comment out code and leave it there

  - if you aren't using it, delete it

Then you end up with something like this this

```
package com.Example.application;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.MailTo;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

    final Context context = this;
    private WebView webView;
    private ImageButton btnrefresh;    
    private TextView txtrefresh;
    private Menu optionsMenu;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
    private View mCustomView;




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //define button 
        btnrefresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        btnrefresh.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnrefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //define textView
        txtrefresh = (TextView)findViewById((R.id.textView1));
        txtrefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        if(isConnected())
        {

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

            webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                        sendEmail(url.substring(7));
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            initWebView(webView);                         
            webView.loadUrl("http://Example.com/");             
        }
        else
        {
            RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);
            rel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    refresh();
                }
            });
            btnrefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            txtrefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Connection !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }       
    }

    private void sendEmail(String add) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { add });
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        }

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.optionsMenu = menu;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.airport_menuRefresh:
                webView.reload();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Refeshing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Complete with your code
                return true;
            case R.id.goBack:
                if(webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.goForward:
                if(webView.canGoForward()) {
                    webView.goForward();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void refresh()
    {
        if (isConnected()) {
            btnrefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtrefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                        sendEmail(url.substring(7));
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
            initWebView(webView);       
            webView.loadUrl("http://Example.com/");         

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Connection !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }       
    }



    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else                    
            return false;    
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                alertbox.setTitle("Do You Want To Exit ?");
                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { 
                        // finish used for destroyed activity
                        exit();
                    }
                });

                alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // Nothing will be happened when clicked on no button 
                        // of Dialog     
                    }
                });

                alertbox.show();
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        public void exit()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //refresh ImageButton function
            if (v == btnrefresh) 
            {
                refresh();
            }
        }

        private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
            try {
                Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
                m.invoke(obj, args);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void initWebView(WebView webView) {
            WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            settings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

            methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
            methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
            methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
            methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
            methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.clearFormData();
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        }

        UploadHandler mUploadHandler;
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == Controller.FILE_SELECTED) {
                // Chose a file from the file picker.
                if (mUploadHandler != null) {
                    mUploadHandler.onResult(resultCode, intent);
                }
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
            public MyWebChromeClient() {

            }
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            private String getTitleFromUrl(String url) {
                String title = url;
                try {
                    URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                    String host = urlObj.getHost();
                    if (host != null && !host.isEmpty()) {
                        return urlObj.getProtocol() + "://" + host;
                    }
                    if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
                        String fileName = urlObj.getFile();
                        if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                            return fileName;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // ignore
                }

                return title;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        result.confirm();
                    }
                }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
                return true;
                // return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

                String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        result.confirm();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        result.cancel();
                    }
                }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
                return true;

                // return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
            }

            // Android 2.x
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            // Android 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "", "filesystem");
            }

            // Android 4.1
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUploadHandler = new UploadHandler(new Controller());
                mUploadHandler.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
            }
        };

        class Controller {
            final static int FILE_SELECTED = 4;

            Activity getActivity() {
                return MainActivity.this;
            }
        }


        class UploadHandler {
            /*
            * The Object used to inform the WebView of the file to upload.
            */
            private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
            private String mCameraFilePath;
            private boolean mHandled;
            private boolean mCaughtActivityNotFoundException;
            private Controller mController;
            public UploadHandler(Controller controller) {
                mController = controller;
            }
            String getFilePath() {
                return mCameraFilePath;
            }
            boolean handled() {
                return mHandled;
            }
            void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && mCaughtActivityNotFoundException) {
                    // Couldn't resolve an activity, we are going to try again so skip
                    // this result.
                    mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
                    return;
                }
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
                        : intent.getData();
                // As we ask the camera to save the result of the user taking
                // a picture, the camera application does not return anything other
                // than RESULT_OK. So we need to check whether the file we expected
                // was written to disk in the in the case that we
                // did not get an intent returned but did get a RESULT_OK. If it was,
                // we assume that this result has came back from the camera.
                if (result == null && intent == null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    File cameraFile = new File(mCameraFilePath);
                    if (cameraFile.exists()) {
                        result = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
                        // Broadcast to the media scanner that we have a new photo
                        // so it will be added into the gallery for the user.
                        mController.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
                    }
                }
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mHandled = true;
                mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
            }
            void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                final String imageMimeType = "image/*";
                final String videoMimeType = "video/*";
                final String audioMimeType = "audio/*";
                final String mediaSourceKey = "capture";
                final String mediaSourceValueCamera = "camera";
                final String mediaSourceValueFileSystem = "filesystem";
                final String mediaSourceValueCamcorder = "camcorder";
                final String mediaSourceValueMicrophone = "microphone";
                // According to the spec, media source can be 'filesystem' or 'camera' or 'camcorder'
                // or 'microphone' and the default value should be 'filesystem'.
                String mediaSource = mediaSourceValueFileSystem;
                if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                    // Already a file picker operation in progress.
                    return;
                }
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                // Parse the accept type.
                String params[] = acceptType.split(";");
                String mimeType = params[0];
                if (capture.length() > 0) {
                    mediaSource = capture;
                }
                if (capture.equals(mediaSourceValueFileSystem)) {
                    // To maintain backwards compatibility with the previous implementation
                    // of the media capture API, if the value of the 'capture' attribute is
                    // "filesystem", we should examine the accept-type for a MIME type that
                    // may specify a different capture value.
                    for (String p : params) {
                        String[] keyValue = p.split("=");
                        if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                            // Process key=value parameters.
                            if (mediaSourceKey.equals(keyValue[0])) {
                                mediaSource = keyValue[1];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Ensure it is not still set from a previous upload.
                mCameraFilePath = null;
                if (mimeType.equals(imageMimeType)) {
                    if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamera)) {
                        // Specified 'image/*' and requested the camera, so go ahead and launch the
                        // camera directly.
                        startActivity(createCameraIntent());
                        return;
                    } else {
                        // Specified just 'image/*', capture=filesystem, or an invalid capture parameter.
                        // In all these cases we show a traditional picker filetered on accept type
                        // so launch an intent for both the Camera and image/* OPENABLE.
                        Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent());
                        chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(imageMimeType));
                        startActivity(chooser);
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (mimeType.equals(videoMimeType)) {
                    if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamcorder)) {
                        // Specified 'video/*' and requested the camcorder, so go ahead and launch the
                        // camcorder directly.
                        startActivity(createCamcorderIntent());
                        return;
                } else {
                        // Specified just 'video/*', capture=filesystem or an invalid capture parameter.
                        // In all these cases we show an intent for the traditional file picker, filtered
                        // on accept type so launch an intent for both camcorder and video/* OPENABLE.
                        Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCamcorderIntent());
                        chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(videoMimeType));
                        startActivity(chooser);
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (mimeType.equals(audioMimeType)) {
                    if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueMicrophone)) {
                        // Specified 'audio/*' and requested microphone, so go ahead and launch the sound
                        // recorder.
                        startActivity(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                        return;
                    } else {
                        // Specified just 'audio/*',  capture=filesystem of an invalid capture parameter.
                        // In all these cases so go ahead and launch an intent for both the sound
                        // recorder and audio/* OPENABLE.
                        Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                        chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(audioMimeType));
                        startActivity(chooser);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                // No special handling based on the accept type was necessary, so trigger the default
                // file upload chooser.
                startActivity(createDefaultOpenableIntent());
            }
            private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
                try {
                    mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // No installed app was able to handle the intent that
                    // we sent, so fallback to the default file upload control.
                    try {
                        mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = true;
                        mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(createDefaultOpenableIntent(),
                                Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
                        // Nothing can return us a file, so file upload is effectively disabled.
                        Toast.makeText(mController.getActivity(), R.string.uploads_disabled,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            private Intent createDefaultOpenableIntent() {
                // Create and return a chooser with the default OPENABLE
                // actions including the camera, camcorder and sound
                // recorder where available.
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent(), createCamcorderIntent(),
                        createSoundRecorderIntent());
                chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, i);
                return chooser;
            }
            private Intent createChooserIntent(Intent... intents) {
                Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
                chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,
                        mController.getActivity().getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.choose_upload));
                return chooser;
            }
            private Intent createOpenableIntent(String type) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType(type);
                return i;
            }
            private Intent createCameraIntent() {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                        File.separator + "browser-photos");
                cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
                mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath)));
                return cameraIntent;
            }
            private Intent createCamcorderIntent() {
                return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            }
            private Intent createSoundRecorderIntent() {
                return new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I had done all this I saw that you had things like this.

> ```
> webView.loadUrl("http://Example.com/");
>
> // Complete with your code
>
> webView.loadUrl("http://Example.com/");
> ```

These tell me that this isn't code that you have written yourself.

Comment: Hello Sir, 
Thanks for the input... But i Am not getting the point
[link](webView.loadUrl("http://Example.com/");)

Comment: have I wriiten it twice

Comment: it makes this look like example code.

Comment: Actually I asked my Senior wrote that part and commented a part for me to write